# permission does not exist in manifest, but exists in app info

Tags: android, permissions

in my app's manifest there is no permission for storage but when I'm looking at app's info in app setting it shows that there is storage permission,
how can I remove it?

[image: app info permission]

this is how my manifest look like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: have you added any lib in your project?

Comment: it probably is in some library that you use.

Comment: @NileshRathod yes, google maps, firebase, a download manager,..

Comment: may be one of any library using that permission @ElProgrammer

Comment: Definitely Download manager is using storage permission

Comment: @KapilRajput I'm using ThinDownloadManager, I will check it

Comment: @KapilRajput It wasn't the downloadManager

Comment: @ElProgrammer any other lib you are using?

Comment: @ElProgrammer if you want to have ThinDownloadManager in your project you have to use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ` in your manifest then why you want to remove storage permission

Comment: @KapilRajput I don't use the downloadManager to save file in the external storage

Comment: @ElProgrammer post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @KapilRajput I found it, by Abhi answer , thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to merge manifest tab in Android studio to find out exactly where is permission originating from. Refer here

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts

Answer (score 2):

if any permission is not in your manifest file and showing it in app info then there must be some libraries that using that permission, you can see all these permissions used by other libs in AndroidManifest-> **Merged Manifest** tab

u can also use **tools:node="remove"** in your permission like this in your main **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

these permissions will not show in App Info